# Most useful .NET utility classes developers tend to reinvent rather than reuse

Tags: .net

I recently read this Phil Haack post ([The Most Useful .NET Utility Classes Developers Tend To Reinvent Rather Than Reuse](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/06/13/the-most-useful-.net-utility-classes-developers-tend-to-reinvent.aspx)) from last year, and thought I'd see if anyone has any additions to the list.

Comment: This should be CW

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hidden .NET Base Class Library Classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122784/hidden-net-base-class-library-classes)

Answer (score 47):

People tend to use the following which is ugly and bound to fail:

```
string path = basePath + "\\" + fileName;
```

Better and safer way:

```
string path = Path.Combine(basePath, fileName);
```

Also I've seen people writing custom method to read all bytes from file.
This one comes quite handy:

```
byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(path); // use path from Path.Combine
```

As [TheXenocide](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8543/thexenocide) pointed out, same applies for `File.ReadAllText()` and `File.ReadAllLines()`

Comment: Same for File.ReadAllText and File.WriteAllText

Comment: I think that i must be one of the 5 people that actually use those off the vat!

Comment: Nice one. I just learned something new.

Answer (score 36):

`String.IsNullOrEmpty()`

Comment: Although there was some hoopla about IsNullOrEmpty breaking if in nested loops a couple of years ago...

Comment: I'm not so sure I remember anything of the sort, I've used it in fairly nested loops and algorithms since .NET 1.0

Comment: I like to create an "IsNullOrEmpty" [and "IsNotNullOrEmpty"] extension method for strings... does that count as reinventing?

Comment: Does IsNullOrEmpty() check if the string.Trim() == string.empty as well?

Comment: @KallDrexx I think they were planning to add the whitespace-only check in c# 4

Comment: @KallDrexx: No, it does a simple check against `null` and `Length == 0`

Comment: @KallDrexx There is (atleast in .NET 4.0) a method called String.IsNullOrWhitespace()

Answer (score 35):

```
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(string path)
```

Returns the file name of the specified path string without the extension.

```
Path.GetTempFileName()
```

Creates a uniquely named, zero-byte temporary file on disk and returns the full path of that file.

Comment: Does GetTempFileName really create a zero-byte file on disk? What a poorly named method if that is the case....

Comment: It avoids race conditions (which could be a security hole) -- once it's returned the filename, it's guaranteed to exist.

Comment: The method is still poorly named.  Let's invent method Path.CreateTempfile() which returns a temporary filename but doesn't actually create the file.  It'll be bad because of race conditions, but it'll be as perfectly well named as GetTempFileName.

Comment: The equivalent method that _doesn't_ create the file is called [`GetRandomFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getrandomfilename.aspx).

Comment: @Windowsprogrammer It seems to be called that way because [the same function in the Win32 API is called that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364991(v=vs.85).aspx). Not that that's a good reason to keep naming functions badly, but just sayin'.

Answer (score 28):

The `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` class.

Comment: That's great!  Didn't know this one existed.  It does such a simple thing but it's nice to have it wrapped up already.

Answer (score 23):

String.Format.

The number of times I've seen

```
return "£" & iSomeValue
```

rather than

```
return String.Format ("{0:c}", iSomeValue)
```

or people appending percent signs - things like that.

Comment: String.Format was implemented for C++ migrators. 
return "£" & iSomeValue is far easier to write. Personally I hate String.Format.

Comment: @Stimpy, string.Format() is better for localization.

Comment: This is not localization, this is replacing correct data with wrong data. If something is £5 you should show £5, not $5. £5 is not $5.

Answer (score 22):

Enum.Parse()

Comment: "reflection => slow" is a ridiculous generalization and oversimplification.  To use the type, the assembly must be already loaded into memory. Hence, the "reflection" used here is just getting an reference to an existing array.  You could not do better rolling your own.

Comment: Toro, why do you program .NET at all? It's slow..

Answer (score 20):

String.Join()   (however, almost everyone knows about string.Split and seems to use it every chance they get...)

Comment: Why would I use String.Join over a plus sign?

Comment: I'm guessing you are confusing String.Join (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) with String.Concat. (Plus is an alias for the latter.)

Comment: +1. It's silly how often I see someone reinvent the wheel by creating a StringBuilder, making a boolean for isFirstElement, and foreaching through a collection, prepending ", " before each element except the first. Just add the items to a List<string>, then call ToArray() and string.Join().

Comment: Still PHP has a nice option: skip null (or empty) strings when joining. So, when you are execute `String.Join(", ", LastName, FirstName)` and LastName or FirstName is suddenly null or String.Empty, you don't have ugly `", Doe"` or `"John, "`, but `"Doe"` or `"John"` respectively.

Comment: @JoeWhite Just to update for anyone that stumbles upon this - as of .NET 4 there are overloads that take an `IEnumerable<T>` or `IEnumerable<string>` so no need for `ToArray()`:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421 :-)

Answer (score 20):

Trying to figure out where My Documents lives on a user's computer.  Just use the following:

```
string directory =
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

Comment: In VB.Net: My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialFolders.MyDocuments

Answer (score 20):

I needed to download some files recently in a windows application. I found the DownloadFile method on the WebClient object:

```
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.DownloadFile(sourceURLAddress, destFileName);
```

Answer (score 14):

Hard coding a / into a directory manipulation string versus using:

```
IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
```

Comment: Why not Path.Combine and ignore DirectorySeparatorChar altogether.

Comment: there have been situations where I've needed the character alone

Comment: Although there is no real disadvantage putting a "/" instead of bothering with long variable name. No one cares about Mono 99% of the time anyway. And I don't see any other good reason to use it.

Comment: "/" would work fine in Mono. It's "\" that's Windows-specific (though "/" works for most WinAPIs too).

Answer (score 13):

The **StringBuilder** class and especially the Method **AppendFormat**.

P.S.: If you are looking for String Operations performance measurement:
[StringBuilder vs. String / Fast String Operations with .NET 2.0](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/StringBuilder_vs_String.aspx)

Comment: See the StringWriter class too!

Answer (score 12):

```
Environment.NewLine
```

Answer (score 12):

Instead of generating a file name with a Guid, just use:

```
Path.GetRandomFileName()
```

Answer (score 10):

Lots of the new Linq features seem pretty unknown:

**`Any<T>() & All<T>()`**

```
if( myCollection.Any( x => x.IsSomething ) )
    //...

bool allValid = myCollection.All( 
    x => x.IsValid );
```

**`ToList<T>(), ToArray<T>(), ToDictionary<T>()`**

```
var newDict = myCollection.ToDictionary(
    x => x.Name,
    x => x.Value );
```

**`First<T>(), FirstOrDefault<T>()`**

```
return dbAccessor.GetFromTable( id ).
    FirstOrDefault();
```

**`Where<T>()`**

```
//instead of
foreach( Type item in myCollection )
    if( item.IsValid )
         //do stuff

//you can also do
foreach( var item in myCollection.Where( x => x.IsValid ) )
    //do stuff

//note only a simple sample - the logic could be a lot more complex
```

All really useful little functions that you can use outside of the Linq syntax.

Answer (score 9):

- Using [DebuggerDisplay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x810d419.aspx) attribute
  instead of ToString() to simplify
  the debugging.
- [Enumerable.Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx)
- [Tuples](http://rabdullin.com/using-tuples-in-c/) from FSharp.Core!

Answer (score 8):

System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex

Comment: I'd actually go the other way -- where many people will immedaitely jump to a regex solution to a problem, even if there's a simpler & faster non-regex method.

Comment: BAH!  Regex is FRIGGEN AWESOME.  Away with your dismissive comment!

Comment: Yay for responding 4 years in the future! But it's worth saying.. Regex is FRIGGEN SLOW!!!! String.Split() works for all but the most complicated things and if you use it with the right overloads it's pretty quick too.

Answer (score 8):

`input.StartsWith("stuff")` instead of `Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^stuff")`

Comment: except input.StartsWith() will perform about 10x better. YAGNI and KISS!

Comment: Hah! Right you are. Edited to put them in the right order.

Comment: Not only that, but StartsWith() has nice semantics built-in - the person reading this knows exactly what is intended.

Comment: Upmodding for the comments, not the post...

Comment: Why would you resort to RegEx when there is already a method to do exactly what you need?

Answer (score 8):

See [Hidden .NET Base Class Library Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122784/hidden-net-base-class-library-classes)

Answer (score 8):

For all it's hidden away under the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace, [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) is actually a very nice csv parser.  I see a lot of people either roll their own (badly) or use something like the nice [Fast CSV](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx) library on Code Plex, not even knowing this is already baked into the framework.

Answer (score 6):

File stuff.

```
using System.IO;

File.Exists(FileNamePath)

Directory.Exists(strDirPath)

File.Move(currentLocation, newLocation);

File.Delete(fileToDelete);

Directory.CreateDirectory(directory)

System.IO.FileStream file = System.IO.File.Create(fullFilePath);
```

Answer (score 6):

`System.IO.File.ReadAllText` vs writing logic using a StreamReader for small files.

`System.IO.File.WriteAllText` vs writing logic using a StreamWriter for small files.

Comment: I think you meant System.IO.File.ReadAllText, System.IO.File.WriteAllText.

Answer (score 4):

Many people seem to like stepping through an XML file manually to find something rather than use XPathNaviagator.

Comment: I always like to read the XML into a datatable then filter on that. Lovely, lovely datatables!

Comment: I'm not familar with XML -> DataTables.  Doesn't it require that the XML be one tiered (mean that XML was a poor choice for the data to start with)

Answer (score 4):

Most people forget that Directory.CreateDirectory() degrades gracefully if the folder already exists, and wrap it with a pointless, if (!Directory.Exists(....)) call.

Comment: This is untrue.  In ASP.NET 2.0 (my test), Directory.CreateDirectory(some path) will throw an exception if the directory already exists.

Comment: You may have something else going on if it throws an exception, like the directory being readonly or an existing **file** of the same name as the path you're trying to create.

Answer (score 1):

myString.Equals(anotherString)

and options including culture-specific ones.

I bet that at least 50% of developers write something like: if (s == "id") {...}

Comment: Although string is a reference type, the equality operators (== and !=) are defined to compare the values of string objects, not references. This makes testing for string equality more intuitive. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score -5):

Path.Append is always forgotten in stuff I have seen.

Comment: There is no such method. Do you mean Path.Combine?